# Let's get critical: Dec 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Magento Stack Exchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: I think I've said this before..."Come on graduation!!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Watching Add to Cart Event - quote item id is empty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10662/watching-add-to-cart-event-quote-item-id-is-empty)

**Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How do I get the MySQL affected rows using the Magento resource?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10623/how-do-i-get-the-mysql-affected-rows-using-the-magento-resource)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Best practice to join product attributes](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10212/best-practice-to-join-product-attributes)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How can I make a cart header automatically dropdown when a product is added using Ajax or Javascript?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10512/how-can-i-make-a-cart-header-automatically-dropdown-when-a-product-is-added-usin)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Magento htaccess error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10961/magento-htaccess-error)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Moving from production site to live](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10014/moving-from-production-site-to-live)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [debugging magento code on xampp using netbeans and xdebug](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10885/debugging-magento-code-on-xampp-using-netbeans-and-xdebug)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 6)

---

- [unable to create order in the backend- button/links aren't responding](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10066/unable-to-create-order-in-the-backend-button-links-arent-responding)

**Net Score: -6** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 6)

---

- [Magento APC User Cached Misses](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10424/magento-apc-user-cached-misses)

**Net Score: -7** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 7)

---

- [Get notified by just mail](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10895/get-notified-by-just-mail)

**Net Score: -10** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 10)

---

Comment: I guess this means at least 3 more months of "school". Who do we have to bribe here to graduate?

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion when a new user comes to StackExchange people should keep attention to his/her questions and should be treated nicely. Because some doesn't have enough knowledge in Magento and he/she may asking simple questions in a complex manner. So if we answer that user with expert answer he/she won't get the exact idea how to solve the question. Instead better to provide answers that can be understandable according to his/her knowledge level. The first impression always affects the users to come to site or avoid it.